# lock inside lock

Tags: c#, locking

I'm wondering if this construction will cause an error:

```
lock(sync)
{
  // something
  lock(sync)
  {
    //something
    lock(sync)
    {
      //something
    }
  }
}
```

I've run this code, and it seems fine, but maybe in some circumstances an error may be thrown?

Comment: Why do you want to use such a construct?

Comment: Can you describe some situation where you'd need to do so? I'm trying to figure out that, but..?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer A recursive function may lock the same resource.

Comment: @todda.speot.is Ah... But a lock, inside a lock, inside a lock... it's very strange, isn't it? :D But thanks for this clarification!

Comment: @todda.speot.is I mean, without a recursive function.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I can't think of a practical purpose to explicitly write code like this. Unless you're a really bad programmer, and you have code to the effect that something is calling `Monitor.Exit` outside of your `lock` statements.

Comment: @todda.speot.is In fact, that's why I did the question in my first comment. I believe OP should give us some code sample where he's doing that thing or question seems to be useless...

Comment: The question is quite useful ... it's the first google hit for "C# lock within lock". The code obviously wouldn't be written literally like that ... the inner locks would occur in methods called by the code doing the outer locks (and no, not recursively, usually). This is a common pattern and the purpose of the question should be evident to any experienced programmer.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[`lock` is a wrapper for `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

> The `lock` keyword calls `Enter` at the start of the block and `Exit` at the end of the block. From the former's documentation:

[From the documentation for `Monitor.Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx):

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke `Enter` more than once without it blocking; however, an equal number of `Exit` calls must be invoked before other threads waiting on the object will unblock.

Because the calls to `Enter` and `Exit` are paired, your code pattern has well defined behaviour.

Note, however, that `lock` is not guaranteed to be an exception-less construct:

> A `ThreadInterruptedException` is thrown if `Interrupt` interrupts a thread that is waiting to enter a `lock` statement.

Comment: Worth noting that the inner `lock`s are essentially redundant: you already *have* the lock; asking for it again will never fail.

Comment: It really isn't worth noting that, as it is common for methods holding locks to call methods that also obtain locks. In some designs, the second lock would deadlock ... I've worked on such systems, and it was necessary for the program to maintain its own reference count and only take and release the lock at the outermost level.

Comment: I agree with Jim. I just had an instance where in an MVC application I needed an inner lock. I chose to place a lock statement at inserts and updates with the same key, and then I have one area in the controller that I lock, where I close the report; this collects data for an error report, then calls the necessary DAL methods, some methods that are reused and can be called by other processes outside of the report. I wanted to freeze any database changes during the closing, so the error report is accurate and nothing sneaks in. So yes, there are reasons where a nested lock isn't redundant.

Answer (score 21):

To explain why it is well-defined behavior and will never fail:

Aside: [This answer has better details about how locks actually work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11272662/356218)

The lock occurs at the `Thread` level, so calling it a second time on the same thread will be redundant.  I would think it would not have any performance penalty (although that would depend on how exactly the internals of .Net are written, so I can't guarantee that)

Many times you'd have a public function that calls another public function in your class, whom both need the lock when used seperately.  If this was not allowed the following would fail:

```
private Dictionary<string, int> database = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private object databaseLock = new object();
public void AddOrUpdate(string item)
{
    lock (databaseLock)
    {
        if (Exists(item))
            database.Add(item, 1);
        else
            ++database[item];
    }
}
public bool Exists(string item)
{
    lock (databaseLock)
    {
        //... Maybe some pre-processing of the key or item...
        return database.ContainsKey(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was trying to work out whether lock within lock of the same object would work, precisely because one method calls another.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx)) this is well-defined behaviour and causes no problem.