# .Net BlockingCollection not work with Parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach, blockingcollection

I have tried to feed a dictionary with the values of a BlockingCollection

```cs
(...)

lock (blockingCol)
{
    lock (cache)
    {
        cache = new Dictionary<Guid, customDocument>();

        Parallel.ForEach(blockingCol,
            (document) =>
            {
                lock (cache) //Same bug with or without this lock
                    cache.Add(document.Id, document);
            });

        blockingCol = new BlockingCollection<customDocument>();

        (...)
    }

     (...)
}

(...)
```

The problem is sometimes the document is already in the `cache`. But I don't understand why. I create a new `cache` before and the `BlockingCollection` should not dequeue the same document twice. But I think it's a problem of the `Parallel` because when I use the code under this it's work but I need a multithreading system here.

```cs
(...)

lock (blockingCol)
{
    lock (cache)
    {
        cache = new Dictionary<Guid, customDocument>();

        while (blockingCol.Count > 0)
        {
            var doc = _blockingCol.Take();
            cache.Add(doc.Id, doc);
        }

        blockingCol = new BlockingCollection<customDocument>();

        (...)
    }

    (...)
}

(...)
```

Comment: Admittedly, my multi-threading-fu is not strong, but I'm surprised this code does not deadlock being that you `lock(cache)` inside of a `lock(cache)`. Race condition, maybe?

Comment: Actually, on second look, I see that you assign to `cache` inside of the outer lock. Since `cache` now points to a new object, I suppose that's why there wouldn't be a deadlock.

Comment: If i understand corrrectly this : [Lock inside lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172934/lock-inside-lock). I can because it's the same thread. But it's not multithreading... I'm agree with you, here I can't lock in a lock.

Comment: Just a fyi. If you are using a blocking collection you need to call `.GetConsumingEnumerable()` and pass that enumerable in to your foreach blocks.

Comment: Just a fyi. Afaik a `BlockingCollection<T>` is already threadsafe and if you swap the `Dictionary<T>` with a `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` you do not need the locks anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is neither with BlockingCollection nor with Parallel.ForEach() call nor with locking, though you can get rid of explicit locking with proper usage of concurrent data structures. It is with the fact that you are using a plain Dictionary<> inside multithreaded code.

Rewrite your snippet to be

```
    Parallel.ForEach(blockingCol.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
        (document) =>
        {
             cache.AddOrUpdate(document.Id, document, (k,v) => document);
        });
```

and it will get rid of the exception, `ArgumentException` with message 'An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary.'

While this solves your immediate problem, you should rewrite the section completely to be simply

```
cache = blockingCol.ToDictionary( d => d.Id );
```

That `Parallel.ForEach()` does not buy you anything in terms of performance.

Also, check your producer side to make sure it does not put two documents with same Id.